# Sequelize return response with nested loops

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am looping through and inserting elements in my `addAll` method. Once this has finished, I would like to return a response. My code currently works, but I am not sure how to get the response to happen.

**Route**

```
.post(function (req, res) {
    var screening_module = Screening_module.build();

    screening_module.screening_module = req.body.module;
    screening_module.screening_module.organization_id = req.user.organization_id;
    screening_module.addAll(function (success) {
            res.json({message: 'screening_module created!'});
        },
        function (err) {
            res.status(err).send(err);
        }); });
```

**AddAll**

```
addAll: function (onSuccess, onError) {
    var screening_module = this.screening_module;
    screening_module.selectedUser.forEach(function (user) {
        Screening_module.create({
            organization_id: screening_module.organization_id,
            supervisor: screening_module.supervisor.id,
            name: screening_module.name,
            description: screening_module.description,
            deadline: screening_module.deadline,
            category_id: screening_module.category.id,
            screening_module_type_id: screening_module.type.id,
            user_id: user.id
        }).then(function (createdScreeningModule) {
            Screening.create({
                user_id: createdScreeningModule.dataValues.user_id,
                screening_module_id: createdScreeningModule[null]
            }).then(function (createdScreening) {
                screening_module.selectedSkillsets.forEach(function (skillset) {
                    Screening_has_skillset.create({
                        screening_id: createdScreening[null],
                        skillset_id: skillset.id
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promise is your friend here

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

addAll: function (onSuccess, onError) {
    var screening_module = this.screening_module;
    Promise.each(screening_module.selectedUser, function (user) {
        return Screening_module.create({
            organization_id: screening_module.organization_id,
            supervisor: screening_module.supervisor.id,
            name: screening_module.name,
            description: screening_module.description,
            deadline: screening_module.deadline,
            category_id: screening_module.category.id,
            screening_module_type_id: screening_module.type.id,
            user_id: user.id
        }).then(function (createdScreeningModule) {
            return Screening.create({
                user_id: createdScreeningModule.dataValues.user_id,
                screening_module_id: createdScreeningModule[null]
            }).then(function (createdScreening) {
                return Promise.each(screening_module.selectedSkillsets, function (skillset) {
                    return Screening_has_skillset.create({
                        screening_id: createdScreening[null],
                        skillset_id: skillset.id
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }).then(onSuccess, onError);
},
```

Untested, but hopefully give you an idea of how to handle. *IMO, this kind of deep nesting is a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), and you might need to consider the design again*